# Import error with "import pyspark.pandas "

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

This is part of new coursework I am doing.
I am trying to install pyspark and I intend to use pyspark.pandas .  I try to run a check on my package like this.

`import pandas as pd`

`import numpy as np`

`import pyspark.pandas as ps`

But as I run imports, I see the below error.

`ImportError: cannot import name 'print_exec' from 'pyspark.cloudpickle' (C:\Users\smith\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\cloudpickle\__init__.py)`

The pyspark version I am using is 3.1.3. I am not sure, I could be wrong at setting paths here. Is there a way I can verify the paths?? Or this could be any other issue please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: `from pyspark import pandas as ps` try this

Comment: Hi, Thankyou. I tried it  but this also does not work. Still gives the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas API is available only for PySpark version 3.2, or above.

To upgrade PySpark to its latest release execute the following command:

```py
!pip install -U --upgrade pyspark
```

> Remove the "!" if you're not executing the command on a Jupyter Notebook.

After restarting your kernel `import pyspark.pandas as ps` import should work.

#### Note

You can also check the PySpark version Python is importing like so:

```py
import pyspark

print(pyspark.__version__)
# 3.3.0
```

#### Update

I've had a look at the history of changes made to `broadcast.py` (that I believe is where the import is failing), and it seems they've changed the location of `print_exc` from `pyspark.cloudpickle` to `pyspark.util`. Upgrading should really solve the issue.

**Older version of `broadcast.py` module:**

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/75ea89ad94ca76646e4697cf98c78d14c6e2695f/python/pyspark/broadcast.py#L24

**Newer versions:**

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/8f744783531d4f62abdf82643b5eb34d54a2820b/python/pyspark/broadcast.py#L42

Comment: Thankyou the update worked for me. But now I am seeing another error   "ImportError: cannot import name 'TimestampNTZType' from 'pyspark.sql.types' "

Comment: Are you sure the update worked, and that your PySpark is version 3.3.0? I did a `pip install pyspark==3.1.3` , and in PySpark 3.1.3 there's no TimestampNTZType  class inside pyspark.sql.types. However, using 3.3.0 the import works fine. Try the `import pyspark` followed by `pyspark.__version__`, to check which version Python is actually importing.

Comment: If Python is really importing the updated PySpark version, I would suggest you reinstall PySpark. First, you'll need to execute `pip uninstall -y pyspark`, then just run a `pip install pyspark`. If you get a permission error, add the `-U` option to the last command: `pip install -U pyspark`. Additionally, if you're using an environment manager, like Anaconda or virtualenv, don't forget to activate your environment before executing any of the aforementioned commands. For example, `conda activate MY-ENV`, or `python -m venv <your virtual environment name>`